# Unforunately app has stopped ,Converter app

Tags: android

I was practicing making this converter app, it's a simple converter but when i launch my app in my phone it says "Unfortunately, "app" has stopped". This converter is based on a Vogella Android Tutorial about making a converter. I just added a few things myself.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text; 

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView dollarText;
TextView euroText;
EditText enterText;
EditText result;
RadioButton dollarRadio;
RadioButton euroRadio;
RadioButton deci;
ImageButton imgB;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    enterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterNumbers);
    result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);
    RadioGroup newRadio = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    euroText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.euroTextView);
    dollarText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dollarTextView);
    imgB = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    imgB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.buttonConvert:
                    dollarRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonLek);
                    euroRadio = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButtonEuro);
                    if(enterText.getText().length() == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Please enter numbers",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    double userInput = Double.parseDouble(enterText.getText().toString());
                    if(dollarRadio.isChecked()){
                        result.setText(String.valueOf(convertToDollar(userInput)));
                        dollarRadio.setChecked(true);
                        euroRadio.setChecked(false);
                    }else{
                        result.setText(String.valueOf(convertToEuro(userInput)));
                        dollarRadio.setChecked(false);
                        euroRadio.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    newRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(dollarRadio.isChecked()){
                euroText.setText("Dollar");
                dollarText.setText("Euro");
            }else{
                euroText.setText("Euro");
                dollarText.setText("Dollar");
            }
        }
    });

    deci.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            DecimalFormat newDeci = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
            String s = newDeci.format(result);
            result.setText(s);
        }
    });
}
public static double convertToDollar(double euro){
    return euro / 0.88;
}
public static double convertToEuro(double dollar){
    return dollar * 0.88;
}
}
```

log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kushtrimmhconverter.converter/com.example.kushtrimmhconverter.converter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kushtrimmhconverter.converter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
```

...

```
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.kushtrimmhconverter.converter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: add an output of your error log

Comment: complete errorlog??? you can not see where the errors coming from

Comment: Which line is line# 78??

Comment: Which line is MainActivity.java:78?

Comment: `deci.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `RadioButton` `deci` without initializing it that's why your class is throwing NPE

Add this in `onCreate()` method

```
deci = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.deci); // change the id as per your layout
```

Also, you should put these lines in `onCreate()`. Probably not right now but in future it might give you same trouble you are facing right now. Unless you have making it visible on button click (although I can't see it in your code).

Answer (score 1):

`deci` is never initialized, so it is `null`, so `NullPointerException` when calling `deci.setOnCheckedChangeListener`